# Javascript find() method is crashing my function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, function

I'm trying to figure out how to make my function return false when I send a number that isn't available in my object.

```
 const getUnitColor = (unitNumber: any): any => {
    const color = getColor.unit.find((unit: any) => {
      return unit.number === parseInt(unitNumber);
    }).unitColor[0].color;
    if (color) {
      return '#' + color;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
  
  console.log(getUnitColor("1"))

  console.log(getUnitColor("0")) // should return false
```

The error I'm getting for the second console log is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unitColor' of undefined" when it should be returning false.

JS Fiddle has 1 of the sample data I'm passing
https://jsfiddle.net/jdhax4y9/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
?.unitColor[0].color;
```

or assign the result of find and return the value.

```
const color = getColor.unit.find((unit: any) => {
  return unit.number === parseInt(unitNumber);
});

if (color) {
  return '#' + color.unitColor[0].color;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this works:

```
const getUnitColor = (unitNumber) => {
    const foundColor = getColor.unit.find(function(unit){
      return unit.number === parseInt(unitNumber);
    })
    if (foundColor) {
      return '#' + foundColor.unitColor[0].color;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```